# Magento 2.1.1 Unable to save parent category

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to save category from admin panel
but not able to save parent category, it fire **error :: Something went wrong while saving the category.**

Comment: Refresh the page and try to save it again.

Comment: Remove var folder from root and login again

Comment: i've tried with refreshing page and tried but not working @kri

Comment: i've removed var folder and pub folder also and regenerate but still not :( @Rakesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found Solution, Override below file
**app/code/Magento/UrlRewrite/Model/Storage/DbStorage.php**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4430

and Replace the foreach loop with the following on line no - 94:

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
   $urlArray = $url->toArray();
   $urlPath = $urlArray['request_path'];
   $storeId = $urlArray['store_id'];
   $dataKey = $storeId.'..'.$urlPath;
   $data[$dataKey] = $urlArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when was trying to save category with a huge amount of products. Try to switch "Store View" to some store (not "All store views") on the top of category admin page and then select a category to save it. It should help